# POST method not working for permitAll

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have following configuration with spring security:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/login",
                        "/webResources/**",
                        "/app/**",
                        "/",
                        "/core/landingPage",
                        "/api/genders",
                        "/ums/signup").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                .and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and().csrf()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied");
```

The problem is that /ums/signup is a PostMapping and its not working. Whenever I try to hit this endpoint it redirects me to login page. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show your `/ums/signup` class declaration and method declaration ?

Answer (score -1):

Override the overloaded configure method `public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception` and add

```
web.ignoring().antMatchers("/ums/signup");
```